# How to implement OpenID connect in Node JS using Okta tool

Tags: openid-connect, openid, google-openid, okta-api, openid-provider

I am not expert in this topic. I referred many documentation, many video for implement OpenID concept in Node JS using Okta. But I couldn't understand. How it's processing and How to use any one explain this topic and share some example code using Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at my [first tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/) which is a good match for someone new to OAuth and OpenID Connect. It provides a code sample that you can repoint and explains how to use endpoints from both an API and a Web UI.